# Handling Terraform recreating AWS subnets that have load balancers attached causing a deadlock

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws

So I have two projects, separated and isolated from each other, using separate terraform state files to manage themselves.

**Project A:** The VPC, networking, subnets, eip, gw layer. This project is a shared VPC for all projects in my working group. We launch all our projects within this same VPC

**Project B:** The application, load balancers, security groups, ecs containers, api-gateway. This project is the application itself, you configure the load balancer accordingly with the security groups that allow whatever ports it needs and runs the software on ecs.

**The problem:**
When I wanted to change a few small things in the VPC configuration, not even actual information, just some names of resources, it seems I accidentally triggered a recreate of the subnets. This means it'll try to delete them. But it can't because there are load balancers attached to it. So it constantly fails. It's deadlocked now cause I have 20 projects deployed each with their own load balancer

How do I manage this so the VPC can be reconfigured without always triggering problems that cause me to have to destroy and recreate the whole application suite each time. This seems a really annoying problem to always have to think of that solution when in my case, I actually didn't change anything in the subnets, just normalised the terraform resource names.

Comment: There are many resource types where seemingly simple changes aren't supported by the API. In many cases, name changes are one of these. Subnet name changes definitely are. If you edit your question with the _exact_ resources that you changed, and what you tried to change, it's possible that someone will answer with "there's your problem." But you would probably get a faster answer looking at the docs (and if the Terraform docs aren't clear about what triggers a replacement versus an update, CloudFormation docs are).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are changing the Terraform resource names you can edit the state file to rename these in the state as well.

You can do this by using the [`terraform state mv` command](https://www.terraform.io/docs/commands/state/mv.html).

So if you had something like this before:

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}

resource "aws_subnet" "az-a" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"

  availability_zone = "${data.aws_region.current.name}-a"

  tags = {
    Name = "Main"
  }
}
```

and then renamed the resource from `az-a` to `az_a` to follow Terraform's general naming pattern of using underscores instead of hyphens as an example:

```
data "aws_region" "current" {}

resource "aws_subnet" "az-a" {
  vpc_id     = "${aws_vpc.main.id}"
  cidr_block = "10.0.1.0/24"

  availability_zone = "${data.aws_region.current.name}-a"

  tags = {
    Name = "Main"
  }
}
```

Terraform would see that you have "deleted" the resource `aws_subnet.az-a` and then created a brand new resource called `aws_subnet.az_a` and ignore the fact that these 2 resources are otherwise equal. As such it would then want to destroy the `aws_subnet.az-a` resource on the next apply and create `aws_subnet.az_a`.

In this case if you run:

```
terraform state mv aws_subnet.az-a aws_subnet.az_a
```

Then Terraform will rename the resource in state and the next plan will show an empty diff.

You can also use this when refactoring your code to move resources in and out of modules like this example of moving the subnet resource into a module called `vpc`:

```
terraform state mv aws_subnet.az_a module.vpc.aws_subnet.az_a
```

Comment: wow thats a use of terraform I've not seen before, thank you!